# If $x^4\equiv86\mod{125}$, how to find $x$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> If $x^4\equiv86\mod{125}$, how to find $x$ ?

We had a Proposition that; (only $(ii)$ is relevant in this example) [image]

[image]

$\textbf{Questions}$

$1)$ (In the $9$th line of the example) Why must be $b$ one of $16,36,56,76,96$ (How to conlude it from $2^{16}\equiv 86\mod{25}$)

$2)$ (In the $10-11$th line) How can we reduce $2^{96}\equiv 86\mod{125}$ to $4y\equiv 96\mod{100}$ ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say $2^b \equiv 86 \pmod {125}$, then we must have: $2^b \equiv 86 \pmod{25}$, but we know that $2^{16} \equiv 86 \pmod{25}$, so we must have: $2^b \equiv 2^{16} \pmod {25}$, or in other words $2^{b-16} \equiv 1 \pmod {25}$, but since the order of $(\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is 20, then we must have:

$$b = 16 + 20k; \text{ for some non-negative integer k}$$

Now simularly the order of $(\mathbb{Z}/125\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is 100 we must have:

$$b = 16 + 20k + 100s$$

But since the group is cyclic and $20 \cdot 5=100$, it's enough to check when $s=0$, and $k \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$, which yields $b \in \{16,36,56,76,96\}$

For the second part, note that $2$ is generator of the group, hence every number in the group can be written as a power of 2 in $(\mathbb{Z}/125\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. Now let's say:

$$z^4 \equiv 86 \equiv 2^{96} \pmod {125}$$

Now let's say $z=2^y$, then we have:

$$2^{4y} \equiv 2^{96} \pmod{125}$$
$$2^{4y - 96} \equiv 1 \pmod{125}$$

Now since the order of $(\mathbb{Z}/125\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is $100$, we must have:

$$4y - 96 \equiv 0 \pmod{100}$$